# How to automatically update MS-Access 2007 application

Tags: ms-access

I have a front-end Access 2007 apllication which talks to MySql server.

I want to have a feature where the application on the user's computer can detect that there is a new version on the network (which is not difficult) and download the latest version to the local drive and launch it.

Does anybody has any knowledge or exprience how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you actually **need** to find out if there is a newer version?

We have a similar setup as well, and we just copy the frontend and all related files **every time** someone starts the application.

Our users don't start Access or the frontend itself. They actually start a batch file which looks something like this:

```
@echo off
xcopy x:\soft\frontend.mde c:\app\ /Y
c:\app\frontend.mde
```

When we started writing our app, we thought about auto-updating as well and decided that just copying everything everytime is enough.

We have enough bandwidth, so the copying doesn't create any performance problems (with about 200 users).

Plus, it makes some things easier for me as a developer when I can be sure that each time the application is started, the frontend is overwritten anyway.
I don't have to care about auto-compacting the frontend when it's closed (and users complaining that closing the app takes too long...), and I don't have to deal with corrupted frontends after crashes.

---

**@Lumis - concerning the custom icon:**
Ok, maybe I should have made this more clear. There is only **one** batch file, and it's in the same network folder as the frontend.
The users just have links on their desktops which all point to the same batch file in the network folder.
This means that:

1. future changes to the batch file are easy, because it's only one single
   file in one central place
2. we **can** change the icon, because
   what the user sees is a normal Windows link

*(By the way, we did **not** change the icon. Our app is for internal use only, and I'm working in a manufacturing company, which means that all but very few users are absolutely non-technical and couldn't care less about the icon, as long as it's the same on all machines and they know how it looks like so they can find it quickly on their desktop...)*

Comment: This solution works, but I cannot assing a custom icon to a batch file, which matters for a more user-friendly and professional look. I agree that when the user start the database once a day it is not too much data traffic.

Comment: Why had you considered auto-compacting (compact on close) the FE in the first place?  If your app uses local tables for temporary data or user-specific data, put them in a separate local database and link to those tables from the FE.  It seems highly unusual you would have any other reasons to compact an MDE FE.  In any case, avoid auto-compact.

Comment: @HansUp: Yes, only because of local tables. Good point though, we never thought of putting temp tables in a separate local database.

Comment: @Christian Specht You may find this link useful then: http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/bloatfe.htm

Comment: @Christian, ok I see, I can create a shortcut to the batch file. Sometimes windows ask for a special permission to run a network batch file so the user has to click twice. Have you had this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't remember anymore. The app (including the batch file to start it) is running since the beginning of 2003. Maybe our admins changed some permission stuff back then...

Comment: We ended up including a check for a new version, rather than copying every time because most of our users are remote from the file server and on a link that's rather slow. It saves a lot of startup time.

Answer (score 2):

Tony Toews has one: [Access Auto FE Updater](https://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2009/11/14/two-new-versions-of-the-auto-fe-updater-are-available.aspx)

It appears to be free, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yep its free and rather good, I rolled my own that uses the same idea before I found that one

Comment: I am not sure how does this work, do I have to email users every time I have an update or do they just click the same link on their desktop, initially generated by this utility?

Comment: Free as in b**r - no. It's nag-ware after 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

Lumis's option is solid, however if you want to check the version and only copy the database when their is a new version, have a 'Version' field in a back end table, and a 'Version' constant in a front end module.  Keep these in sync with each new production release.  Compare the table version against the version in the module when the main form of the front end database opens.

If they don't match, have the database close, but have the database call a batch file as the last bit of code to run as it's closing.  The database should finish closing before the batch file begins it's copy process.  If needed, place a minor delay in the batch file code just to be sure there are no file locking issues.