# All of my reports in MS Access were suddenly deleted

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Okay, so I have a couple of hundred reports in my MS Access database (yes, it's a big project, and yes, we should switch to SQL Server). I was working on one of the reports yesterday and was suddenly disconnected from the network. I have been having a lot of network outages at work, and I think it has something to do with the sudden disappearance of all the reports. I have never had admin privileges to set up Backup and Restore on my machine, and have had to back up the database manually myself.

My most recent version is from a week ago, but I have done A LOT of work since then. My question is whether or not a sudden disconnection from the network (and, subsequently, the database I was working in), could have caused the deletion, and whether or not it is possible to restore the database without having Backup and Restore set up on my computer.

Please help.

Edit: My databases are in a front-end/back-end format. It was the front-end database (with the reports, queries, and forms) that crashed, but the only items that were deleted were the reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It your database was corrupted once, it's hard to tell if it's possible to restore your missing reports from it.

The only 100% safe way to restore your changes would be to have a recent backup from before the corruption happened.

But it's definitely possible that a network outage, while users accessed the database **and** you made changes in the reports at the same time, lead to corrupting the file.

---

I know that it doesn't help you right now, but here is some advice for the future:

You should think about splitting your Access database in a front-end (which contains forms, reports and code) and a back-end (which only contains tables).

The back-end will be located on a central machine, and each user will have his own copy of the front-end.

Of course splitting the database and ensuring that the front-ends are automatically updated on the user's machines will require some initial work, but you will gain two benefits from it:

1. When you work on the front-end, you are working on your local machine, so you are less affected by network outages.
2. The back-end is more unlikely to be corrupted. As you unfortunately experienced yourself, changing reports, forms and code in an Access database that's in production use at the same time can lead to issues.

Plus, even if you're not able to set up Backup and Restore on your computer, you should backup your work more often. I do this several times a day by just copying the Access database manually (you will do this automatically without thinking once you're used to it).

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, it wasn't really clear from the question that your database *is* split into front-end and back-end.
The network outage stuff made me think that you were editing the "one and only central database".

I don't remember that I ever experienced something like that by myself, so I can just guess what you could do **now**.

One thing that comes to my mind is that you could try to export your reports (given that you know their names) to text files with the undocumented `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` commands:

```
'save your report in a text file on your disk
Application.SaveAsText acReport, "YourReport", "c:\YourReport.txt"

'load your report from the text file in another Access database
Application.LoadFromText acReport, "YourReport", "c:\YourReport.txt"
```

But this is just an idea, so I don't know if this will work in your case.
Maybe the reports are still there (and just not shown for some reason), then it might work.

I'm sorry to say this again, but:
Honestly, I don't have a lot of experience in repairing corrupted databases (not Access, and neither SQL Server, for which I'm responsible at work!) because I try very hard to **never** come in a situation like yours by frequently taking backups. **LOTS** of them (I've been called "paranoid" by co-workers because of that).

---

**EDIT 2:**

I just read in your comment to phoog's answer that the corrupted database was on the network (i.e. you edited it while it was on the network).

Advice for the future:
**Don't ever do this**, for the reasons that phoog already mentioned in his answer. If the database is already split into front-end and back-end, make a copy of the front-end and edit it on your local machine to prevent such stuff from happening again.

Plus, if the front-end with the reports is used by several users, don't let them all work on the same file on the network (for the same reason).
It's incredibly easy to give each user his own copy, including auto-updating when there's a new version of the front-end.
You can read here how I'm doing this at work:
[How to automatically update MS-Access 2007 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253366/how-to-automatically-update-ms-access-2007-application/6254209#6254209)

Comment: Actually, my database is exactly in that format. It was the front-end database (with the reports, queries, and forms) that crashed, but the only items that were deleted were the reports (all of them).

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves open several important points:

How is your application set up?
Is the MDB containing the reports on your network?
Are the tables in the same file or another one?
If the tables are in another file, where is it located?

Access is notoriously susceptible to data loss and file corruption when network connectivity is spotty.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528 (the section "Additional best practices for network environments") for more information.

The information in this article ("How to troubleshoot and to repair a damaged Access 2002 or later database" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283849) may help

Any files that you have on the network should have been backed up by your network administrators, so ask them for the most recent backup before you lost your reports.  With luck, this will be more recent than your own most recent backup.

Comment: Hey phoog, the database containing the reports is on the network. However, it is only linked to the tables in my backend database (also on the network), but does not actually have it's own tables. After reading the first article, I'm not sure if my set up is considered 'high-stress' since I'm not using Access with any other applications, but I can see how the environment itself could be labeled as high-stress since I have 3 or 4 different front-ends connecting at any given time. Maybe that has something to do with it as well. I'll try the trouble shooting though. Thanks for the link

Comment: The fact that the MDB (or ACCDB, I should have said earlier) is on the network is the source of the vulnerability, because *the process that writes to the file is on your computer*, even if the front and back end files are in the same network location.  So the danger is that the connectivity might be interrupted in the middle of a write operation, which leaves the file in a corrupt state.