# MS Access / Sharepoint Online link to Database to allow multiple users / VBA?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Ok, our current problem is the classical "trying to allow multiple users access onto one fe file (this is in runtime currently)" - This cannot be handled (at least in AC2007) and is best solved by installing a FE on each computer that is using it.

This poses another problem for us, we have many employees who we want to be able to have access to it, yet the program probably doesn't warrent our techs to push out updates of this file to each computer with their "patches" (plus there may be added costs to doing such for us).

We would really prefer the ability for users to open a link from our internal portal to the file as can be currently achieved. We are mulling over the possibility of pushing out 4 or 5 copies of the FE application on a shared folder and creating an Access program that would essentially check to see if a FE app is open say FE1 and if so it would open FE2 (and so on) then close the sharepoint linked database that did the checking so a new user could open that. This would allow multiple users access to the same BE information using the same FE program.... would this work? Any ideas of how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works, the idea is to create a function that checks for the open file, if it finds its open it replies with an error, on the error you can move to the following database. Here is a sample code:

```
 Option Explicit


Function FileLocked(strFileName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   Open strFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
   Close #1
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
  Application.FollowHyperlink "c:\MasterMAX.accdr"
  DoCmd.CloseDatabase
  End If

   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Application.FollowHyperlink "c:\MasterMAX2.accdr"
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't know anything about SharePoint, so I can't say if my proposed solution is still viable when SharePoint is involved.*

If your problem is just how to distribute the file to all machines, why don't you let your users start a batch file that copies the Access frontend from a network share to each machine and starts it?

We are doing something similar at work (without SharePoint, though), and I described our setup here:
[How to automatically update MS-Access 2007 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253366/how-to-automatically-update-ms-access-2007-application/6254209#6254209)

We have put the batch file on a network share as well. The users have just shortcuts on their desktops to the batch file on the network share, so it's easy to update the batch file as well.
Maybe you can do something similar (let the users run the batch file from SharePoint, which copies and starts the Access frontend).