# Front end solution for a growing business

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, database-design

I work for a workers comp insurance provider.  About 10 years ago, the company probably had 20-30 employees.  Around that time, they built a bunch of databases using ms access because it was quick and easy.  Today, the company has close to 200 employees and we're still using ms access for all of our front-ends.  (We have switched the back ends to sql server).  Needless to say, we frequently experience difficulties with so many people using the access front ends at the same time.

My question is, what's a better front-end entry system for our company?  Should I learn ASP.net and build web based front ends?

Comment: Why build something? Unless your company does something unique, there should be plenty of off the shelf products.

Comment: "Needless to say"..?  What kind of problems?  Problems with query duration?  Is Access connecting via ODBC and executing sprocs on the server-side?  If so, I've had pretty good success with this.  Otherwise, provide more details and maybe someone can help with specific issues you're seeing.

Comment: Are you saying that you use Access-Forms....but those Access-Forms use linked-tables that hit a back-end Sql Server?

Comment: 1. Our company does a ton of unique things.
2. One problem we have is updating front ends.  Our users are usually in them, so it's hard to get exclusive access. Another issue that occasionally users is that users will personalize form layouts not realizing that it will change everyone's layout.
3. Yes, I'm talking about using access forms that use linked tables that hit a back-end Sql Server

Comment: @BenGorman: The problem of not having exclusive access goes away when you give each user their own frontend, as described in my answer. [Here's another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6254209/6884) where I describe how we're doing this at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we frequently experience difficulties with so many people using the access front ends at the same time.

This sounds like there is **one** copy of each frontend somewhere on a network share, which is used by all your users at once.

If yes: **don't do that!**
Instead, give each user his own copy of the frontend on his machine (for example by letting them execute a batch file which copies the newest version of the frontend to the local machine and starts it).

This will probably cause most of your problems to go away. At work, we are using Access front-ends with SQL Server backends with more than 200 users and don't have any problems.